# Where to find custom beamer themes

Tags: beamer, templates

I don't like default beamer themes very much.

Where could I find some custom beamer themes?

Comment: Speaking for the community of people who watch math talks, I would love to see more beamer themes!  :-)) But you can start by customizing one.  [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/) is a nice Adobe web app to find color schemes.

Comment: Yeah, don't use a blue-heavy colour theme. This alone will make you stand out.

Comment: Related: [Are there any repositories of “killer slides” for `beamer`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7586/5764)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

All (or at least most) of the default themes are available to view [here](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/). If none of these suit, I think the best bet is probably to pick one you almost like and modify it yourself. This has the advantage that you learn more about beamer, and it makes your presentations unique. The [beamer manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) is pretty complete and all the relevant options are documented...

Customising a theme does not involve hunting out the `.sty` file in your `texmf` tree and editing that: you can just modify options piecemeal in your preamble. For example, a recent beamer preamble of mine starts like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=darkred!80!black}
```

Note that first I pick some theme options, then (the final line) I redefine the colour of the itemize item. As long as the command comes *after* the colortheme option, this gives you an easy way to modify a beamer theme on the fly. [I think I did this because the beaver theme is red, but it doesn't actually redefine the itemize colour, so you get the default blue unless you fix it.]

There are some custom themes available [here](http://latex.simon04.net/). But I'm sure you know about this because you obviously googled "[custom beamer themes](http://www.google.com/search?q=custom+beamer+themes)" before you asked a question on here.

Comment: Thanks. The idea of writing my own theme isn't a bad one, but I'm afraid it'll take much time and that my result won't be that good. I already got into that page, but was hoping to find a bigger repository with tons of custom themes...

Comment: @peoro I think you might be overestimating the size of the beamer community. I think it's unlikely that there would be a huge repository of custom beamer themes that isn't showing up on the first page of that google search. There just aren't enough people making their own themes... I don't think it would take too long if you find a theme you more or less like and learn just how to modify it...

Comment: How do you figure out how the element you want to change is named? For instance, using `CambridgeUS` theme I want to change the background color of the section's short title.

Answer (score 21):

This may be a shameless plug, but I ported a Powerpoint and a Powerdot theme to Beamer. They are available here: https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports. Here is what they look like:

[image: median theme]

[image: klope theme]

I would be happy to receive improvement suggestions, feature requests and bug reports.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I've been forgetting this for too long already but I've used Median and it was really smooth, thanks for this theme. Very balanced (though I tweaked here and there :P)

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the feedback! If any of your mentioned tweaks fix bugs or improve the layout in some way, feel free to share them with me. (Don't know much about Git/Bitbucket but I think this could be a "pull request".)

Comment: 5 years, is it still maintained?

Comment: @hola I have indeed not updated the themes for a few years, but if you find issues please report them as BitBucket issues and I'll look into them.

Answer (score 20):

Some additions that I did not see in the links provided by Seamus:

- The [progressbar Beamer theme](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php) with a customizable progress bar at the frame bottom
- The [Keynote theme](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/02/beamer-and-latex-with-keynote-theme/)

Comment: is that version of the progress bar clickable? I saw a version where you could click a part of the progress bar and it would go to that frame of the talk...

Comment: @Seamus: afaik that progressbar doesn't respond to clicks.

Comment: @Seamus You may have a look at [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344539/106776) for a clickable progress bar.

Comment: Link for Keynote theme seems unavailable

Answer (score 9):

I found one here : [McGill like Beamer style](http://structdynviblab.mcgill.ca/archives/layoutBeamerMcGill.7z) but the coding does not look so good. Do you want something completely different from existing themes? Otherwise, you can start from an existing one and slowly modify parameters (colors, margins, bullets and so on)

Comment: Unfortunatly the link seems to be not reachable anymore. Did the source moved or was it deleted?

Comment: @Tobi Nicely updated.

Answer (score 7):

You can visit the site

https://www.overleaf.com/

Specifically:

https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/presentation

Comment: Also [Shalatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations) has many beamer templates.

Comment: Found some nice themes there, I recommend checking the metropolis theme: https://github.com/matze/mtheme

Answer (score 6):

I have made several flat beamer themes, which have clickable progress bars. They are available here: [Beamer theme Mathz](https://github.com/lvjr/theme) .

Answer (score 2):

Uwe Ziegenhagen created an overview of all the beamer themes available in TeXlive. This includes both the themes which come with the beamer class as well as 3rd party themes:

https://github.com/UweZiegenhagen/LaTeX-Beamer-Theme-Overview/blob/main/OVERVIEW.md

Here a screenshot of the first theme in the list:

[image]

Comment: @Marijn Ups, thanks!

Comment: Great, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my current list (some are already mentioned)

- https://hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/
- https://de.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/presentation
- https://awesomeopensource.com/project/martinbjeldbak/ultimate-beamer-theme-list or https://github.com/martinbjeldbak/ultimate-beamer-theme-list
- https://latex.simon04.net/

Comment: +1: Not sure why you had a downvote.