# Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, themes

No matter how hard I search, I cannot find *any* information on creating a Beamer theme from scratch, as opposed to LEGOing it together from the built-in inner, outer and color themes, maybe modifying one or two beamer templates by using cryptic commands without explanation.

The reason I want to do this is that *none* of the built-in inner, outer and color themes suit my taste. All of them are instantly recognisable as Beamer, and there is very small visual change between them.

What I would like to implement is something along the lines of certain PowerPoint templates:
[image: powerpoint template 1]
[image: powerpoint template 2]

and I would also like to port the beautiful [`powerdot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/powerdot) themes (see [gallery](http://www.shantanukulkarni.org/powerdot/pdgallery.html)), such as the KlopeSpring theme to Beamer, as Powerdot is very inconvenient for having to convert all images to EPS.

So how do I go about all those geometric decorations and placing text above/below/on them?
Oh, and I almost forgot to mention that I know about the easy solution of "include an empty slide PDF as background image", but that is no fun.

Comment: This question might be helpful to you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26299/215

Comment: Have you seen this document? http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf

Comment: @FilBot3 Yes, but at the time of asking this question, it was not as complete, informational and helpful as Claudio's answer below. I haven't checked if it was expanded lately.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

Build your own theme: no one forces you to exploit predefined inner, outer, color and font themes. Look at [this theme](http://www.guitex.org/home/en/forum/5-tex-e-latex/66391-beamer-template-per-universita-sapienza#67006): is it *instantly recognisable as Beamer* ?

But, let's have a practical example: it is one hour-built theme, thus take it just for demonstration. Lot of improvements can be done. The reference is one of your pictures.

We call this new theme `texsx` mainly due to the fact that I don't have much fantasy with names. So in a directory we create the following files:

1. `beamercolorthemetexsx.sty`
2. `beamerinnerthemetexsx.sty`
3. `beamerouterthemetexsx.sty`
4. `beamerthemetexsx.sty`
5. `texsx-example.tex`

To build the theme we might exploit TikZ: very likely you can avoid it, but the question has the magic tag, so I felt almost obligated (even if the true reason is: with TikZ was faster `;)` ).

So we keep `beamerthemetexsx.sty` very simple:

```
\mode<presentation>

% Requirement
\RequirePackage{tikz}

% Settings
\useinnertheme{texsx}
\useoutertheme{texsx}
\usecolortheme{texsx}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]  

\mode<all>
```

we load the themes, remove the navigation symbols and define blocks aspect.

Now, let's start define the title page in the `inner` theme. As we need to test what we're doing, at first is is better to set up the example document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
\date[ISPN ’80]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers}
\author[Euclid]{Euclid of Alexandria \texttt{euclid@alexandria.edu}}

\usetheme{texsx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Nothing is strange or difficult till now. Time to build the titlepage; I would proceed as follows:

- exploit the `background` template to set the titlepage background
- define a `title page` template in which the title, the author and the date are actually set.

The operations described are translated in `beamerinnerthemetexsx.sty` in the following way:

```
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \fill[color=brown] (0,2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \fill[color=orange] (0,0) rectangle(2.95,1.9);
  \fill[color=blue!50!cyan!80] (3.05,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.9);
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
   \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
   \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{texsx}[1][]
{ 
   \vskip6cm%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,sep=8pt,#1]{title page header}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip0.75cm%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
     \vskip0.2cm%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
}

\mode
<all>
```

It is important to notice that we define ourself the bounding box through `\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);` then, thanks to the test on the page number, we apply the background on the title page only.

In the `title page` template then we actually put the elements mentioned above. We characterize their color aspect passing to `beamercolorboxes` `title page header`, `author`, `date` so we need these definitions. Let's add them to the `beamercolorthemetexsx.sty`:

```
\mode<presentation>

% Settings
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}

\mode
<all>
```

Now, if we compile our example we get:

[image]

Cool!

Let's going on defining the aspect of the frame title. This is done with a template called `frametitle` in the `beamerouterthemetexsx.sty`, which looks like:

```
\mode<presentation>

% Frame title
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{texsx}[1][]
{
\vskip1cm%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.2cm]{frametitle} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox[fill=white](0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2);
  \fill[orange] (0,0) rectangle(2.95,1.2);
  \fill[blue!50!cyan!80] (3.05,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2);
   \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      {\node[anchor=west, white,font=\large] at (3.2,0.61){\insertframetitle};}
      \else%
      {\node[anchor= west, white,font=\large] at (3.2,0.81){\insertframetitle};%
       \node[anchor= west, white,font=\small] at (3.2,0.41){\insertframesubtitle};}%
      \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\mode<all>
```

Basically, we exploit the same concept of the titlepage to draw some boxes; then we check whether the subtitle is present: accordingly we set the position of title and subtitle or we set only the frame title with TikZ nodes.

We need again tests to verify our idea. So let's add something on our example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{There Is No Largest Prime Number}
\date[ISPN ’80]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers}
\author[Euclid]{Euclid of Alexandria \texttt{euclid@alexandria.edu}}

\usetheme{texsx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number} 
\framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.} 
\begin{theorem}
There is no largest prime number. \end{theorem} 
\begin{enumerate} 
\item<1-| alert@1> Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number. 
\item<2-> Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers. 
\item<3-> Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them. 
\item<1-> But $q + 1$ is greater than $1$, thus divisible by some prime
number not in the first $p$ numbers.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{A longer title}
\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As we also have lists, we have to define their aspect and color. So we need to add:

```
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=orange}
```

in our `beamercolorthemetexsx.sty` and:

```
% Items
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]
```

in `beamerinnerthemetexsx.sty`. It is not mandatory to put the latter definitions in the inner theme, but I followed the Beamer style.

It seems to me we can compile our document; the result is:

[image]

Ok, I agree: the colors are not the ones in the reference picture and the subtitle is not perfectly aligned with the title (this is due to the font size difference), but the new theme is here.

Comment: Basically the reason to not going deeper with it is: launch time. ;)

Comment: ...........Wow.

Comment: I think in this case it is better to use `\setbeamertemplate` every time instead of `\defbeamertemplate*`.

Comment: @marczellm: why? If you have to create themes from scratch I believe it is better go with `\defbeamertemplate`.

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate` syntax is easier, and the docs suggest that `\defbeamertemplate` is intended for predefining templates for the end user to hook into. In this case I'm the end user and I want to leave them fixed.

Comment: If it is for your own purposes, I see your point.

Comment: Doesn't frametitle go into beamerouterthemetexsx.sty and *not* beamercolorthemetexsx.sty?

Comment: How was the animated gif showing of the presentation created?

Comment: @oneself: I typically use GIMP for that. But, you can have a look also to [Converting beamer slides to animated images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23727/13304)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Could you please explain why `useasboundingbox` is important? I am looking to make a tikz rectangle for each standard frame like this: `\path [draw,fill=green!25!black] (current page.north west) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,-3.62cm);`

Comment: @macmadness86: I use that both for the `background` and `frametitle` to be sure not having objects that being large might cause problems to the page. Using a path would not provide cropping facilities.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Then why do you use a height of `1.2` instead of `\the\paperheight`? It is still not clear to me what exactly you are cropping. What objects?

Comment: @macmadness86: That is for the `frametitle`: I don't want it to have an height larger than 1.2 cm. Probably that would never happen anyway, but a double control does not bother.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! If I want to add stuff on the footline (or on the side), what should I do? I tried to edit the `footline` beamer template, but it does not work. Or should I use overlays directly on frametitle?

Comment: @tobiasBora: not sure why it does not work without seeing the code. I believe it deserves a new separate question.

Answer (score 83):

Using Claudio's answer as a starting point, I developed two themes which I made available [here](https://bitbucket.org/marczellm/beamerports), one based on the PowerPoint Median theme and one based on the Powerdot KlopeSpring theme. There may be more to come.

In addition to the techniques Claudio demonstrated, I used the [`textpos`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package to do absolute positioning of text on the page.

In order to achieve different frame backgrounds on section pages and plain frames, I used something like

```
\newcommand{\sectionframe}{{
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{
      % draw the different background
    }
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \frame{\sectionpage}
}}
```

Note the double curly brackets; the inner pair puts everything in a group and thus keeping the template changes local.

Here are some images:

[image: sample slides]

Answer (score 7):

For those of you trying to use a background image behind the title, you can adapt the great answer of Claudio to obtain something like this:

[image]

This is for instance my `beamerinnerthemeubuntu.sty` (for the page title), where `ubuntu-background.jpg` is my image.

```
\mode<presentation>


% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{ubuntu}[1][]
{ 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north east] at (current page.north east)
    {\includegraphics[width=\the\paperwidth,height=\the\paperheight]{ubuntu-background.jpg}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \vskip2cm%
    %% "title page header"  defines the loaded colors.
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,sep=8pt,#1]{title page header}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\huge\inserttitle\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip0.75cm%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{\insertauthor}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
     \vskip0.2cm%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=12cm,leftskip=3cm,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{\insertdate}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
}

\mode
<all>
```

and my outer theme (for the pages):

```
\mode<presentation>

% Frame title
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{ubuntu}[1][]
{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,sharp corners,spread upwards,frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,interior style tile={width=\paperwidth}{ubuntu-background.jpg},before skip=0pt,halign=center]
    \usebeamercolor{frametitle}\color{fg}
    \insertframetitle
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\mode<all>
```

and my `beamerthemeubuntu.sty`

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch
\mode<presentation>

% Requirement
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{noto}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Settings
\useinnertheme{ubuntu}
\useoutertheme{ubuntu}
\usecolortheme{ubuntu}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]  

\mode<all>
```

together with my `beamercolorthemeubuntu.sty` (to configure the colors):

```
\mode<presentation>

% Settings
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}
\mode
<all>
```

You may also like to use:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=My title, frame style tile={width=\paperwidth}{ubuntu-background.jpg}]
    Hello
\end{tcolorbox}
```

to create something like:

[image]