# Odd behavior of tikz in beamer style

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I want to create my own beamer style for my presentations, and I follow [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch) link to do so. I change the title page template as following

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{texsx}[1][]
{ 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node(title)[anchor=north, below = 0.1\textheight of current page.north] {
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,sep=8pt,#1]{title page header}
                \usebeamerfont{title}{\huge\color[rgb]{0,0,1}\inserttitle}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}
        };
        \node(yfigure)[anchor=north, below=0.0cm of title.south] {
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
        }; 
        \node(author)[anchor=north, below = 0.0cm of yfigure.south] {
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[left,sep=8pt,#1]{author}
                \usebeamerfont{author}{\small\color[rgb]{0,0.5,0.5}\insertauthor}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}
        };
        \node(date)[anchor=north, below = 0.0cm of author.south] {
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[left,sep=8pt,#1]{date}
                \usebeamerfont{author}{\small\color[rgb]{0,0.5,0.5}\insertdate}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
%    %        \insertinstitute
}
```

Which results with this output [image]

I find this very odd since the author anchor is `north` and it is set to be `below of yfigure.south` it should be in the middle of the page, not the left.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hard to say without a minimal example. We can't really know what this does out of context. We don't even have the command used or know what, if anything, `#1` is. However, I'd guess that replacing `left` with `center` would work.

Comment: We really need that minimal example. For example your code will not even compile unless I add extra tikz libs.