# Designing a beamer theme from scratch : what to put in inner/outer/color

Tags: beamer

I am trying to impement a beamer theme from my institution's powerpoint theme.
I have started from [Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch), but I have some issues.

First is I do not understand what is the logic behind the different files : in addition to outer inner color, I have also seen a font file. 
So I do not understant what is supposed to go where, and perhaps more importantly, how they interact with each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Beamer Theme Matrix](https://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) can help you to understand how it works. It shows how different `color` themes change every `main` theme. If the whole theme (inner, outer, font, color) was defined inside a unique file, you should modify this file. Being everything divided in independent fragments, just selecting a combination of them provides a new aspect for your presentation.

Section 15.1 Five Flavour Themes in [`beameruserguide`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) clearly explain differences between them. It's easy to imagin what `color` and `font` themes do. `inner` themes define how elements inside a slide (items, enumerate, blocks, ...) look
while `outer` themes define headlines, footlines, sidebar, ...

In fact, all `main` themes are defined as a combination of inner, outer, font and color themes. Just two examples, `AnnArbor` theme is defined with

```
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=yellow!85!orange}
```

while `Copenhagen` is

```
\useoutertheme{split}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
```

Although `beamer` works this way, you don't have to follow it. If you want a constant theme, with very few options, everything can be defined inside a `main` theme file. If your theme is called "mytheme", define everything inside a file called `beamerthememytheme.sty` file and store it into your working folder while you are testing it. As soon as your theme is ready, move it to your local tree.