# How to create a bounding box the size of the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box

I was attempting to create a bounding box across an entire page (as I've seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch) in beamerinnerthemetexsx.sty). However, the box will not flush with the left margin.

As can be seen in this example, setting the margin to 0 works for any text in the document. However the bounding box is not flush with the left margin (it's 15pt off). This both will not allow me to draw in that region, and results in an "Overfull \hbox" error, as the bounding box is trying to span from 15pt right of the left margin to 15pt beyond the edge of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 papersize={254mm,190.5mm},
 margin = 0mm
 }

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
    \draw [->] (0,0) to (10mm,10mm);
    \draw [gray] (0,0) rectangle (40mm,40mm); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{flushleft}
Text will flush with the margins.
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
Unlike the bouding box.
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix this? Should I approaching this a different way entirely?

Comment: Set up the `tikzpicture` as an overlay.  So pass the environment the following in its optional arguments, `remember picture,overlay`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend treating the picture as an overlay.

So you would start the environment as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
```

Even with this, the `tikzpicture` will have its origin `(0,0)` at the point where the picture is *defined*.  So, I would recommend using relative coordinates and redefining where you want your *origin* with respect to the page nodes that TikZ provides.  So here's something that might work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 papersize={254mm,190.5mm},
 margin = 0mm
 }

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

    \draw[line width=4pt,orange] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);

    \path (current page.north west) -- ++ (0mm,-40mm) coordinate (origin);
    \draw [->] (origin) to ++(10mm,10mm);
    \draw [gray] (origin) rectangle ++(40mm,40mm); 

\end{tikzpicture}%%
Hello (flush left) \hspace*{\fill} (flush right) Bye%%

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

Playing with where you place `\noindent` (such as immediately before `Hello`) will show you how the `tikzpicture` is being placed on the page.

If the `tikzpicture` is all that you're going to create with your document, you might want to consider using the `standalone` package.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
%% I like a "border", but that's optional!
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (254mm,190.5mm);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);    

    \draw [->] (origin) to ++(10mm,10mm);
    \draw [gray] (origin) rectangle ++(40mm,40mm); 

\end{tikzpicture}%%

\end{document}
```

Notice how I did not make this an `overlay` in this case.  The above code results in

[image]

If you have other content for your document, either of these approaches can work.

Assuming that you want no other content on the same page as the `tikzpicture`, in the first approach you will have to issue something like

```
\clearpage
```

after the environment.  And by using an overlay, you can use a page geometry more nature for your exposition.

Working with the second approach, you'll want to do something with `\includegraphics` and `\raisebox` to place it appropriately on the page.

If you provided more information about what kind of content you want in the picture, then I could probably give you better feedback.

Answer (score 3):

That's the `\indent`. Add `\noindent` before your `tikzpicture`, this will disable the indent.

If you don't need the indent anywhere in the document, you can use `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to your preamble, which will make it a global option. If you wanted to restore it after the `tikzpicture`, simply write `\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}` (that's the default length).

Also, there's a `page node`, so you can simply write your bounding box as

```
\useasboundingbox (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
```

Comment: Why not just suggest `\noindent` before the environment?

Comment: @A.Ellett Uhh, good point. I guess I had a different train of thought. I will fix the answer.