# How to make the end slide use the same background as title page, while the normal slide use different background?

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

This post relates to another post [How to make company presentation slides template including logos, title slide, normal slide, and ending slide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414120/how-to-make-company-presentation-slides-template-including-logos-title-slide-n). Here I ask more detailed question.

I am making a template for presentation slides using `beamer` class.

I followed the post [Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch) and made the following codes in the file called `beamerinnerthememytheme.sty`.

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \fill[color=mygray] (0,2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
   \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
   \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

However, the code above `ifnum\thepage>1\relax%` let the background only visible on the first page (title page). I want the same background for the ending slide also. Do you know how to do that?

So the logic would be something like:
if the page number is large than `1` or less than `the end`, then `\relax`.

Note that this is meant to be a template, so the number of slides can be different for each case. And people can use

```
\begin{enumerate} 
\item<1-| alert@1> blabla
\item<2-> blablabla
\item<3-> blblbl
\item<1-> blbblblbbl
number not in the first $p$ numbers.
\end{enumerate}
```

This enumerate slides slides have the same page number in the resulting `pdf` file. So, `\inserttotalframenumber` would not work.

Do you know how to do this? Or any other suggestions without using `ifnum ...` are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard coded values like first or last page are IHMO a bad idea. What happens if the titlepage is not the first page of the presentation? Or if a presentation does not have an end slide?

I suggest something like this instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\defbeamertemplate{background}{special frames}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \fill[color=gray] (0,2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\insertendpage}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}[special frames]
    \begin{frame}
            bla bla
    \end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}[special frames]
    \begin{frame}
            text text
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\titlepage

\begin{frame}
  Slide 2
\end{frame}

\insertendpage

\end{document}
```