# How to hide/remove a picture in footline on title slide only, as a template using beamer class

Tags: beamer, graphics, header-footer

I am designing a latex template for presentation slides for my company. I use `beamer` class.

I made the following codes to show a footline on every slide. It is a image on the left, and some words on the right, and the words and image are aligned in the center. However, I want to just remove the image in the title slide.

I have made the following codes

```
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
         \ifnum\insertframenumber=1
         %
         \else
         \includegraphics[align=c, height=1.5cm]{sim-ci-logo-2.png}%
        \fi        
        \hfill%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{myfootlinetext}       
        Company confidential. \textcopyright\, 2018 All rights reserved.\hspace*{1em}
        \insertdate{}\hspace*{2em}
        \insertframenumber\kern1em
 }
```

However, it does not work properly. In the title page, the image is gone, but the words moved to the bottom edge. See the two screenshots below:

This is the title slide's footline, where the words moved to the bottom edge

[image]

This is the normal slide's footline.
[image]

Do you know how to keep the words in the title slide in the same position as other slides? Thanks in advance.

Note that I have used `\ifnum\insertframenumber=1`, assuming title slide is always the first slide. As 
@samcarter pointed out [How to make the end slide use the same background as title page, while the normal slide use different background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414164/how-to-make-the-end-slide-use-the-same-background-as-title-page-while-the-norma), it is usually a bad idea to make such an assumption, but I do not know how to make it. Any suggestion on that is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In exactly the same way as for the background templates, you can have different footlines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\defbeamertemplate{background}{special frames}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \fill[color=gray] (0,2) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
      \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[white,opacity=1] (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{special frames}{text for special footline}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{text for normal footline}

\newcommand{\insertendpage}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}[special frames]
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[special frames]
    \begin{frame}
            bla bla
    \end{frame}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}[special frames]
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[special frames]
    \begin{frame}
            text text
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\titlepage

\begin{frame}
  Slide 2
\end{frame}

\insertendpage

\end{document}
```

---

Quick hack: If you don't want to worry about the vertical position, replace the image by some invisible element of the same height, e.g. a `\rule{0pt}{1.5cm}`