# How can I change theme color and add logo in Beamer (Szeged)

Tags: beamer

How can I alter my presentation from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

With regards to the custom theme color and logo in the bottom left.

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Szeged}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\usepackage{textpos}

%Removes gradient color
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
{
\usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
{%
color(0cm)=(structure.fg!0!bg);
color(1.25cm)=(structure.fg!0!bg)%
}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=}
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip-1.25cm}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section no.1} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title} 
Each frame should have a title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }

\end{document}
```

Hope this is not a duplicate, but I could'nt fine the solution anywhere else.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch) might be what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=teal}

\usetheme{Szeged}

\institute{institute}
\title{text}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%Removes gradient color
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
{
\usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
{%
color(0cm)=(structure.fg!0!bg);
color(1.25cm)=(structure.fg!0!bg)%
}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=}
}
\addtoheadtemplate{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip-1.25cm}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
    \hfill%
    {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute%
    \ifbeamertemplateempty{page number in head/foot}{}{\qquad}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%      
    }%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{minipage}  
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section no.1} 
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title} 
Each frame should have a title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }

\end{document}
```

[image]