# Replicate a particular presentation style with Beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

Is there any idea how can one create the style of the following presentation with Beamer

http://perso.citi.insa-lyon.fr/flemouel/Research/Talks/MCF-Auditions/Presentation-Audit-INSA_Lyon-12_05_2004.pdf

Below a screenshot of the first two pages of the presentation for reference.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the presentation in the question? This would ensure that the question will still be useful for future users in case the external link goes down.

Comment: @samcarter You are right. I provided a screenshot. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I haven't yet seen a beamer theme like this, so I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch is your best bet as a starting point.