# Relative path to .sty theme - nested {color,inner,outer} theme files

Tags: beamer, themes

I've been working through the detailed answer to this question: [Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch) and have a question regarding paths.

I'm building a theme to be used in multiple presentations. I have a directory structure (git repo) as follows:

```
|- Presentations (top-dir)
|
|\_.git (and subfolders)
|
|\_Presentation1
|  |-presentation1.tex
|  \-presentation1.{aux,pdf} etc
|
|\_Presentation2
|  |-presentation2.tex
|  \-presentation2.{aux,pdf} etc
|
\_Theme
   |-beamerthememytheme.sty
   |-beamerinnerthememytheme.sty
   |-beamerouterthememytheme.sty
   \-beamercolorthememytheme.sty
```

I seem to have a few options to use this theme:

- Symbolically link all 4 files into each presentation. Adds to setup cost, can complicate handling with git, but works nicely and doesn't require peculiar handling in the theme files
- Abandon `\usetheme{mytheme}` and use `\usepackage{../Theme/beamerthememytheme}` in the `presentationN.tex` file. This also works for the main .tex file, but seems to require that my theme file now reads `\usepackage{../Theme/beamerinnerthememytheme}` instead of the simpler `\useinnertheme{mytheme}`
- Remove extra files. Use only `beamerthememytheme.sty` and copy the contents of {inner,outer,color} themes into that file. I can also rename to make this simpler by removing the leading `beamertheme` label, since I have to use `\usepackage` anyway. This seems undesirable for readability/maintainability, but I suppose is a tradeoff if the alternatives are complicated.

Is there any way to specify from a .sty file the part that it is included with? In my case, I would imagine I could then go ahead and include `<unknown-inclusion-relative-path>/beamerinnerthememytheme` without concern that I might have presentations want to include this from outside of this directory structure (not a major problem, but would be nice to avoid limiting possibilities whilst I still have ability to easily change).

Comment: I would put the theme files (with a better name than "mytheme") in a folder `themestexmf/tex/latex/mythemes/...` and then add `themestexmf` as a new root to the tex system.

Comment: You can define the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable: `TEXINPUTS=".//;../Theme//;"`

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of Ulrike Fischer in the comments to the question, I ran the following command using the Windows Command Prompt.

```
initexmf --register-root="%cd%"
```

from the top-level directory, having moved the them file into the directory

```
top-level-dir/text/latex/themename
```

and I can now successfully use `\usetheme{themename}`.

The command can be run from a .bat file or similar, making it easier to carry out in a newly cloned repository.

An equivalent Linux script might be something like (untested):

```
initexmf --register-root="$(pwd)"
```

I used the command prompt to avoid possible issues when my 'Linux' prompt is in fact via mingw and git-bash (which often causes path problems converting to/from Windows/Linux).