# Clean slides with slide title on top, name and talk title on bottom

Tags: beamer, presentations

How to create slides like [this](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2017/blob/master/Presentations/A%20Tour%20of%20Deep%20Learning%20with%20C%2B%2B/A%20Tour%20of%20Deep%20Learning%20with%20C%2B%2B%20-%20Peter%20Goldsborough%20-%20CppCon%202017.pdf)? Is there some template that offers this structure (slide title on top, person name, talk title, page number on bottom)?

Comment: How close is the `boadilla` theme to what you want? See here: http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/individual/Boadilla-default-default.html

Comment: @rbrignall I find the blue bar unappealing. The template should be as simple as possible.

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{...}` is the bit that needs changing... give me a few minutes and I'll try to rustle something up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple modification to the `default` beamer theme (which normally has no footline at all, so we add one in).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{title in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{2ex}\insertauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
   \inserttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\title{The Riemann hypothesis in 3 slides}
\author{A.N. Author}
\date{10/02/2020}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of frame}

Text in frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample beamer slide]

Note: I also removed the "navigation symbols" from the page (if you want them back, simply comment out the line `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}`).

If you want to make other changes (e.g. to the colour of the title), I recommend this post, which has various links to other places too: [Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch)

Comment: How can I change the font size of the footer (name, title, page numbers)?

Comment: You could specify it manually in the three `beamercolorbox`es, but the best way is to adjust the styling in the preamble, like this (e.g.): `\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\scriptsize,family=\ttfamily}`