# Creating a simple university Beamer template from scratch

Tags: beamer, templates

## Background

I apologize for not providing any code, but I am just looking for some help getting started.
I am trying to create a *very simple* LaTeX template for my university, nothing fancy. Another university in my country has made this template https://github.com/martstr/beamerthementnu, and I could adapt it for my needs. However, this solution seems *way* too advanced for what I am trying to achieve. Using it would feel like swatting flies with a sledgehammer.

I will make a small list below of what I am trying to achieve. My purpose with this post are some pointers for where to start, and what tools might be best suited to accomplish this task.

- My template only needs two different page types. The first is a frontpage and the second is a plain background.
- I need some settings to switch `language` and change the logo on the frontpage depending on the language chosen.
- I need to select the colors to be used in the template (according to the universitys color specifications).
- The background is just the image depicted below

One of the logo's I need to switch between is shown below

[image]

If possible the frontpage should be structured like this "Tittel dokument " = Document title and the smaller text bellow is an optional subtitle. The text at the bottom is the authors and address field

[image]

Combining the frontpage with the logo should hopefull look something like this

[image]

The plain background looks like this

[image]

## Question

- *I am not asking for a full solution here. I am just looking for some help on how to get started creating my own simple template from scratch.*

Comment: Here is a simmilar question with answers that could help you : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch

Comment: @koleygr Using that link I was able to get started and solve most of my problems. I still have some questions, but they fit better in a follow-up question. If you leave that comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Just marked as a duplicate ... This is how this kind of questions are been closed here ... I can't write an answer that just provides a link of the duplicated question/answer ... Hope you are going to solve the rest of your problems too...