# how to make this slide on beamer

Tags: beamer, themes, beamerposter

I'm a beginner on beamer and I want make this slide .
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Massal, would [Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146529/13304) help?

Comment: How close are you wanting to match what you've shown us?  An exact copy would require a lot of tweaking.  Getting those 6 words and 2 em-dashes would be easy.  In general, we prefer to see what you've tried.  That lets us know how well you understand what you're doing, and gives us a starting point.

Comment: I think this question is reasonable, worth to answer, although it is without MWE. The asker has not shown what he has tried. However, his curiosity on how simple a beamer slide can be (in comparison with PowerPoint, I guess) is understandable and acceptable

Comment: I'm sorry because I didn't clarify my question, it's because it's my first template, I just used the default theme and I wanted to do the same power point presentation I have.

Answer (score 1):

Is this roughly what you have in mind?

[image]

This can be obtained by using vertical space and creating a line (`\hrule`) but needs a bit o tweaking concerning the distances etc. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \vspace{10mm}  % some space from the top
        {\Huge \color{blue}Field of application}\\
        \vspace{2mm}   % some sapc between the text and the line
        \hrule         % the line itself
        \vspace{2mm}   % some space between the line and the following text
        {\Large \color{darkgray}Referential -- Exclusions -- Non-applications}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah! I like this plain beamer!

Comment: thank you very much this is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: you're welcome. please also mark this is the correct answer so that others can also find and use it, thanks!