# Chalkboard background to write on

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, backgrounds

I was wondering if it is possible to create a chalkboard background in LaTeX, like in this picture (minus Bart of course). Then write in the chalkboard using white fill (chalk)?

Is it possible to do this in a non beamer type document class, i.e. not as frames?

[image: chalkboard example]

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a non beamer type document class, i.e. not as frames?

Comment: Although this question seems to be a duplicate of  [beamer-blackboard-theme-and-overlays](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267286/beamer-blackboard-theme-and-overlays) or [i-need-a-beamer-theme-simulating-blackboard-presentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162873/i-need-a-beamer-theme-simulating-blackboard-presentation), I've voted to reopen because OP wants to use it on non-beamer document.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One option could be to desig a chalkboard with `tcolorbox` help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{simpsons}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{chalk}[1][]{
enhanced,
colback={green!40!black},
colupper=white,
fontupper=\ECFAugie\large,
notitle,
sharp corners,
colframe=brown!70!black,
height=.75\linewidth,
boxrule=2mm,
drop fuzzy shadow,
underlay={\tcbvignette{size=2mm, 
    inside node=frame, raised color=brown!70!black}},
#1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{chalk}
\lipsum[2]
\end{chalk}

\begin{chalk}[interior style image=blackboard.jpg]
\lipsum[2]

\hfill\Left\Bart
\end{chalk}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The handwritten font was taken from [samcarter's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165087/1952) answer to [I need a beamer theme simulating blackboard presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162873/i-need-a-beamer-theme-simulating-blackboard-presentation)

And the background image on second example is an edited version of [this blackboard](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Black%28green%29board.jpg)

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I was after. Thanks heaps @Ignasi. I also appreciate the Bart touch.