# Background in Beamer with Tikz

Tags: beamer

How can I draw a blackboard as a background in Beamer? I want something link this[image]

Is there a "chalk font"?

Comment: Welcome, new user.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334341

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48002

Comment: this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356144/1952) can be easily adapted to be used with `beamer`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162873/i-need-a-beamer-theme-simulating-blackboard-presentation

Comment: https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/blackboard-beamer-theme/gcqgjfnkdmqj