# stylish blackboard with tcolorbox or other

Tags: tcolorbox

i'm trying to reproduce a backboard, inserted here as image. So far i've been only able to make a rough imitation. I need to find the right colour values in tcolorbox language and add the shadows, frame bumps, and if possible the effect of hand and chalk writing for text.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{enhanced,varwidth boxed title=0.7\linewidth,
frame hidden,coltext=white,height=6cm, width=8cm, rounded corners,
arc=5mm,borderline={5mm}{0mm}{brown},
valign=center,interior style={top color=green!70!black,bottom color=green!40!black},
#1}

\begin{mybox}
\centering \huge{ABC}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may find clues at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162873

Comment: A blackboard with `tcolorbox: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356144/1952