# \pause command in LaTeX (beyond Beamer)

Tags: pause

Because of the covid-19 pandemic, almost all the people have been forced to teach online. I was using writting apps like xournal, but my writting is awful, so I was looking for apps which emulate a blackboard and where I do not need to write by hand.

Some colleagues are using Beamer, but I would like to emulate a blackboard.

I almost did it, in the sense that I changed the background color and the size of the document in the book LaTeX style, and it seems like a blackboard. But it would be awesome if I could use in either the book or the article style something similar to the Beamer command \pause.

I would like to know is there is a command similar to \pause in Beamer but for normal styles in LaTeX like book and article.

If not, I would like to know how difficult it would be to program it in normal LaTeX.

Moreover, I would like to know if there is a LaTeX package which emulates a blackboard.

[image: This is a topic that I wrote in this emulation of a blackboard in LaTeX -in Spanish-.]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `\pause` is tricky, it would be (much) easier to use beamer but using a style that drops all the header and footer and navigation ornaments and looks more like your image. Then you could use `\pause` and other beamer overlay features `<1>` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already did it in that way, by using directly beamer.

Comment: using beamer really is the answer, as you would have to copy so much beamer code to make this work.

Comment: The `standaloneframe` from the `standalone` class allows you to combine the `\pause` and so on facilities with any geometry you may want to use for your blackboard.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel? See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162873/i-need-a-beamer-theme-simulating-blackboard-presentation) and [here](https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/blackboard-beamer-theme/gcqgjfnkdmqj) and [here](http://www.deanbodenham.com/learn/beamer-blackboard-template-black.html)