# What packages can help me make the following style of slides?

Tags: presentations

Consider the image below
[image]
It looks great for presentation.

My question is what TeX packages render such slides?

Comment: "Looks great" is a matter of opinion `;-)` but this might be a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162873/82917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may be achieved via different methods, I am sending here one idea of how to do it.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid} \usecolortheme{fly}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red!40}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Remove nav. icons

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usebackgroundtemplate
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background-board.png}}

\usepackage{ulem,xcolor}
\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\coloruuline}[2]{%
        \UL@protected\def\temp@uuline{\leavevmode \bgroup
            \UL@setULdepth
            \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2.8\p@\fi
            \markoverwith{\textcolor{#1}{\lower\ULdepth\hbox
                {\kern-.03em\vbox{\hrule width.2em\kern1\p@\hrule}\kern-.03em}}}%
        \ULon}%
        \temp@uuline{#2}%
    }                
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rul}[1]{\coloruuline{red!40}{#1}}

\title[Example]{Beamer example}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{First section}
\begin{frame}[plain]{The ergotic theorem}

\rul{Theorem} (Von Neumann's Ergodic Theorem) 

Let $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu, T)$ be a measure preserving system and $f \in L^{2}(\mu)$. Then

\begin{equation*}
 \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f \circ T^{i} \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(f \mid \mathcal{I}(T))    
\end{equation*}

\vspace{10pt}
\rul{Theorem} (Weak version) 

Let $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu, T)$ be a measure preserving system and $A \in \mathcal{X}, \mu(A)>0 .$ Then

\begin{equation*}
 \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu\left(A \cap T^{-n} A\right) \geq \mu(A)^{2}    
\end{equation*}

\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% EOF
```

**Sample of the output.**
[image]

The background picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I created a new environment for that. I think everything should be described inline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\def\myEmphColor{red}% <== ADAPT COLOR HERE.
\usepackage{amsmath,ulem,ifthen}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=\myEmphColor}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}% Simply use a blackboard-image of correct size here. Sorry for stretching you, Mr. Duck!

\newenvironment{mythm}[1][]{% create new environment with 1 optional parameter.
      \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black}%
      \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black}%
      \begin{block}{{%
         \color{\myEmphColor}\uuline{\color{black}Theorem}}% print 'Theorem' and underline it twice in color 'myEmphColor'.
         \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{ (#1)}}% if given, add the optional theorem name in parentheses.
   }{%
      \end{block}%
   }

\begin{document}   
   \begin{frame}{The ergodic theorem}
      \begin{mythm}[Von Neumann's Ergodic Theorem]
         Let $(X,\mathcal X,\mu,T)$ be a measure preserving system and $f\in L^2(\mu)$. Then
         \begin{equation*}
            \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f\circ T^i\to\mathbb E(f\vert\mathcal I(T)).
         \end{equation*}
      \end{mythm}
      
      \begin{mythm}% <- works without theorem title, too.
         Let $(X,\mathcal X,\mu,T)$ be a measure preserving system and $A\in\mathcal X$, $\mu(A)>0$. Then
         \begin{equation*}
            \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A\cap T^{-n}A)\geq\mu(A)^2.
         \end{equation*}
      \end{mythm}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]