# Beamer presentation with blackboard background cannot find 'faumw8t'

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm working on a lengthier and potentially boring presentation featuring a lot of theoretical work and calculations using the standard beamer class. To make it slightly more attractive and easier to watch, I wanted to switch to a background that looks more pleasant than the base choices, namely a blackboard. Searching around the Internet I found several options. The first one has a working template [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162873/i-need-a-beamer-theme-simulating-blackboard-presentation) and the second one provides instructions [here](http://www.deanbodenham.com/learn/beamer-blackboard-template-black.html). In both cases, I eventually end up with an error upon compiling, related to a file named `faumw8t` missing. I'm afraid I've been unable to understand what this file is and what to do about it. Searching for a solution I found instructions involving tlmgr. Tlmgr didn't work at all so I had to figure that out first, and now when I run the command line

```
tlmgr search --file faumw8t.tfm --global
```

I get

```
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from https://mirrors.nxthost.com/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet!
tlmgr: Cannot load TeX Live database from https://mirrors.nxthost.com/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

I've been using latex for many years now and while I generally manage to figure some technical stuff out, this is completely beyond me. So, in short, I'd like to know what fauw8t is, if there's a way to install it and get that blackboard background to work. I went through the process of installing something called emerald and that seemed to work, but it didn't help in this regard. I'm running Debian 9.13-stretch and my tex version is Texlive-2016.

Thank you!

Edit: I've managed to install the fonts exactly following the instructions [here](https://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) to the letter for texlive and I still have the exact same problem. I don't think updmap is cooperating with my emerald directory in texmf. I don't see it listed when it runs its operations, even though the directory is there.