# Beamer Question Color

Tags: beamer

Which template exists to avoid black and blue colors? The most templates are using either blue or black. Is there something with red or green available?

Comment: Please, look at Beamer Template Gallery, http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/

Comment: Why, yes, of course, have you had a look at the documentation or at the [`beamer matrix`](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Are there any repositories of “killer slides” for `beamer`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7586/5764)

Comment: thanks werner but that was not searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[theme overview sorted by color](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_color.html)

[musing regarding font color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78906/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-piece-of-text-only-on-beamer-mode) that copes with beamer vs. handout mode in addition.

Comment: the point font color is good

Answer (score 1):

If you use a pre-defines style (Madrid, Hannover, Antibe, Warsaw,...) , you can use the command

`\usecolortheme[rgb=0.97,0.35,0.04]{structure}`

Put it in your preamble, and it will adapt the colour of the theme...

Comment: what means rgb?

Comment: maybe red green blue

Comment: It's the international code for describing the colours...

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model

But if you don't want to use these codes, the package `xcolor` has named a lot of colours...

Just add `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`in your preamble, and use these colors :
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors

Comment: @PierreVivegnis that's an assumption that somebody (user29701) prefers the color names when not being familiar with rgb. yes, it would be easy to use SkyBlue for instance, but mostly that will not be a requirement.

Comment: Of course it's not a requirement ! I only suggest it because he didn't seem  very familiar with rgb (neither I am)... It was just a proposition, sorry for the misunderstanding.