# Example of slides presentations using beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

Well I am looking for examples of slides presentations. 
I also want know how to get a pack  that is missing to get when I use texmaker.

Tanx

Comment: Perhaps, what you're after is a combination of the following: [Are there any repositories of “killer slides” for `beamer`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7586/5764) and [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764)

Comment: As you wish. VPK

Comment: Here's a solid [tutorial of Beamer slides](http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/beamer-tutorial.pdf).