# Slide ticker in beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, presentations, mini-frames

I am using 'beamer' for presentations.
I have a Main Titles and a few slides under each.

For example,

Introduction has 4 slides
Methods have 5 slides.

I want to put kind of a ticker at the top of each slide saying what slide we are at currently. For Introduction it should have 4 small circles (coz 4 slides) below it and the slide number should be a highlighted circle.

How can I go about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could choose a beamer theme which supports that. For example `Singapore`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{One}
\begin{frame} text \end{frame}
\subsection{Two}
\begin{frame} text \end{frame}
\subsection{Three}
\begin{frame} text \end{frame}
\subsection{Four}
\begin{frame} text \end{frame}
\section{Methods}
\subsection{One}
\begin{frame} text \end{frame}
\subsection{Two}
\begin{frame} text \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Singapore beamer theme]

Here's the top of a frame, where subsection three of the introduction is highlighted.

Or

```
\usetheme{Szeged}
```

[image: Szeged theme]

Or

```
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
```

[image]

There are related themes such as `Berlin`, `Ilmenau`, `Dresden` and `Frankfurt`, with such a navigation.

Also the [progressbar theme](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php) is interesting, if you wish to show the frame progress.

To visit beamer themes galleries, have a look at [Where to find custom beamer themes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/where-to-find-custom-beamer-themes).

Comment: I used the same style like `Darmstadt` (`split` theme) for my last conference presentations and my colleagues told me at my test run that the mini toc/progress bar on top looks great. It isn't intrusive and gives a nice overview.

Comment: Is it possible to have the "slide ticker" one per slide, instead of one per subsection?