# LaTeX Beamer: Remove Frame Header when new Section starts

Tags: beamer

I want to remove the frame header line every time a new section starts.

I created my own command to do that but I have some problems with the `\ifnum` command.

I tried to use `\ifnum\insertframenumber=\insertsectionstartpage` as a condition to check if a new section starts an then remove the header (like frame 2). LaTeX always seems to execute the else branch, although the condition should evaluate to true... I also tried the `\ifthenelse` command, but it didn't work either.

Does anybody have an explanation for that?

Here my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[t,8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newcommand{\HeaderFrame}[2]{
    \ifnum\insertframenumber=\insertsectionstartpage
        {
            \makeatletter
                \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
                \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
            \makeatother
            \begin{frame}{#1}
                #2
            \end{frame}
        }
    \else
        \begin{frame}{#1}
            \insertframenumber~\insertsectionstartpage
        \end{frame}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test1}

\HeaderFrame{Test}{
    That is a test
}

\section{Test2}

{
    \makeatletter
        \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
        \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
    \makeatother
    \begin{frame}{New Frame}
        Test
    \end{frame}
}

\section{Test3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are comparing apples to oranges. If you want to compare to the framenumber you have to use the section start frame and not page. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302320/36296 how to get the section start frame.

Comment: Btw: In the long run, creating a wrapper command for a frame creates more problems then it solves. Just image you need to use some frame options like `fragile` or `plain`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> based on [Check if page with a given number is a section page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302177/check-if-page-with-a-given-number-is-a-section-page/302320#302320)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcount\beamer@sectionstartframe
\beamer@sectionstartframe=1
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
            \protect\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\beamer@section}{\beamer@sectionstartframe=\c@framenumber\advance\beamer@sectionstartframe by1\relax}{}{}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
        {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\beamer@sectionframes{\the\beamer@sectionstartframe}{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}{}{}
\def\beamer@startframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@endframeofsection{1}
\def\beamer@sectionframes#1#2{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber<#1%
    \else%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber>#2%
    \else%
    \gdef\beamer@startframeofsection{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@endframeofsection{#2}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}
\newcommand\insertsectionstartframe{\beamer@startframeofsection}
\newcommand\insertsectionendframe{\beamer@endframeofsection}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \ifnum\insertsectionstartframe=\insertframenumber%
      \vskip-\headheight%
    \else%
          \leavevmode%
          \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
          \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
            \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
          \else%
            \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
          \fi%
          \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
            \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
              \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
              \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
          \fi%      
      \vskip-0.2pt
      \pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}
      \vskip-2pt
    \fi%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \section{The First}

    \begin{frame}
        First slide
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        Second slide
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        Third slide
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        Fourth slide
    \end{frame}

    \section{The Second}

    \begin{frame}
        First slide
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        Second slide
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        Third slide
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]