# Physics thesis template

Tags: templates, thesis, physics

Do you know where I can find a template to write the thesis? It refers to the bachelor in physics. Is there any site where to find it?

I tried to look but I found only one template and it was too simple. I would need, for example, one with a command that allows you to number the formulas in an orderly manner.

Thanks anyway and I am waiting for your precious answer.

Comment: This probably depends on the university you want to write your thesis at. There may be some aspects you need to do a special way, so doing some research whether your university already provides a template could be a good starting point.

Comment: Equations are numbered in most standard classes: `\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 E = mc^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}` (if the thesis is short, `report` might be better than `book`)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I think you can find an answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/where-to-find-custom-beamer-themes

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Comment: [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates) and [latextemplates](https://www.latextemplates.com/) have many of them.

Comment: The question asks for a feature that is available with every standard class. Every standard class is able to provide the means to write a thesis. I vote to close the question as unclear, especiallly since templates are a bad thing.